# Is there an API or SDK which allows merging FDFs into PDFs and supports Javascript calculated fields?

Tags: pdf, fdf

We have a program which produces PDFs by merging data in FDF files with PDF 'template' and then flattening the form fields to create a final PDF document. Not a problem with CutePDF except for one thing...

One of the templates has a calculated date field that is set by a small bit of Javascript when the PDF is updated. However CutePDF doesn't support Javascript in PDF documents.

I've looked into other products but it's very rare for the feature list to actually mention wether or not the APi supports Javascript calculated fields.

Does anyone know of an API or SDK which allows for merging FDFs into PDFs and also supports Javascript calculated fields?

Comment: As a rule of thumb I would think that APIs for automated PDF manipulation don't support JavaScript because on the one hand JS mostly is used for reacting to user actions and on the other hand automated PDF manipulation most often explicitly does not want interference by some background scripts.

Comment: Thats a good rule of thumb but I do need to know if there are any exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results of my own investigation:

- [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Solutions/FormSDK2.asp): Merges FDF to PDF but does not support calculated fields
- [Debenu Quick PDF Library](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/products/quickpdf/index.php): Neither FDF nor calculated fields
- [PDF-XChange Viewer Pro](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer-pro-sdk): Supports Javascript but not FDF, very helpful support though
- [PDFExpress](http://www.accusoft.com/pdfxpress.htm): Supports XFDF (annotations only) but not FDF
- Adobe PDF Library (via Datalogics): competely incomprehensible and doesn't support either option
- Adobe PDF Library (via Adobe): no answer to enquiry

Comment: If you are still looking for something that supports the calculations in form fields in a PDF, you can try out our [PDF WebAPI](http://dev.datalogics.com/pdf-webapi/fillform/). It supports FDF and handles the calculations in the form as well.